# Microsoft Botframework V4 Calendar Virtual Assistant Azure AD Authentication in Teams getting bad request

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have download virtual assistance skills template and working in Calendar template. It is working in emulator and webchat channel but it is not replying after integrating with teams. OAuthCard Authentication is working in emulator and webchat but it is not working in teams. I have followed MS documents. While debugging from azure using ngrock, it is showing **bad request** .

I have uploaded manifest in teams.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: @JasonSowers  do you have any idea of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Bots on any channel but Teams have the following in the main bot class, where they inherit 'ActivityHandler':

```
 public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
    {
        //...

    }
```

This activity handler is where the oauth is handled.

But in order for oauth to work on Teams, you have to  inherit the TeamsActivityHandler instead. OAuth cards don't work for Teams, so the card sent is tweaked:

```
public class DialogBot<T> : TeamsActivityHandler where T : Dialog
    {
        //...
    }
```